# Disabled Action Buttons - changing formatting

Tags: javascript, css, button, action

I consider myself a novice at css so bear with me :)

I am attempting to change the text color of an action button.  You can see in the image below that "cut" and "copy" are disabled because there is no checkbox selected.

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/2ajcev.gif]

I would like to be able to format both the color of an enabled, and disabled action button.

I did a font-color; addition to the .inputbutton below, but it made the text in the enabled and disabled buttons the same color.

here is a snipped of code from the index.php file which might be applicable...

```
<input type="button" id="actionButtonCut" value="<?php echo $lang_btn_cut; ?>" onClick="actionFunctionCut('','');" disabled class="<?php echo adjustButtonWidth($lang_btn_cut); ?>">
```

here is some code from the style.css file
Full style.css file here: files.#######.com/style.css

```
.inputButton {
padding: 5px;
width: 130px;
border-radius: 3px; 
-moz-border-radius: 3px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
border: 1px solid #2187c0;
background-image:url(../images/button_bg.jpg);
}

.inputButton:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-image:url(../images/button_bg2.jpg);
}

.inputButtonNf {
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

there is also a skin css file with some more formatting
full skin css file here: #########.com/skins/kobus.css

```
/* FTP Action Buttons */    

#ftpActionButtonsDiv {
background-color:#88b0ff;
border-top-color: #404040;
}
```

there is one more ajax.js file although I don't think it is relevant:
http://files.##########.com/ajax.css

Many thanks to anyone who can help me to format both the color of an enabled, and disabled action button :)

Comment: did you try someselector:disabled in you CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>If you don't need IE 8 support,</strike> there is a pseudo-selector you can use `.inputButton:disabled`, <strike>otherwise you may have to fall back to JavaScript.</strike>

Edit: As [dyagmin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3665155/dyagmin) mentioned below, you can use `.inputButton[disabled]` for IE 8.

Comment: This is exactly same, I commented. @tyronius: try it and revert in case you need further help

Comment: .inputButton[disabled] should support IE 8.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks! Tested it just now and it works. You learn something every day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.inputButton:disabled {
background-image:url(../images/some_image.jpg);
}
```

Or you can use background color css property instead of background-image